# Sum of possible all possible $x$ such that $51 \equiv 3 \pmod{x}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I was asked this  simple following question:

> What is the sum of all positive integers $x$ such that :
>   $$51\equiv 3 \pmod{x}$$

My answer is $118$ (and I am pretty sure it's right but would like to check because there are other answers also),

My solution is this :
$$51=kx+3 \Rightarrow 48=kx\quad $$ and $ x>3$ , therefore only $4,6,8,12,16,24,48$ are possible values for $x$ .

Have I missed anything?

Comment: Why not $x = 2$, or $x = 3$. Both hold.  For that matter, the trivial $x = 1$ always holds. Otherwise, all divisors of $48$ ... and you have listed most of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the restriction that $x>3$? It also works when $x\in\{1,2,3\}.$

Aside from that, it looks fine.

Comment: Maybe he wants that the exact remainder of the division of $51$ by $x$ to be $3$ . This would explain why $x>3$ .

Comment: I can't understand the fact  that if we take $1,2,3$  as the answers ,if we divide $51$ by $1,2,3$ ,do we get $3$ as a remainder?

Comment: @Battani The modulo equivalence doesn't give you the remainder .For example this is true : $$15 \equiv 3 \pmod{2}$$ because $$2 \mid 15-3$$ but $3$ isn't the remainder when you divide $15$ by $2$ but rather the modulo holds because $15$ and $3$ have the same remainder ,when you divide by $2$ , namely $1$ .

Comment: @ComplexPhi, i understand now,thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

$51 \equiv 3 \pmod x \iff 48 \equiv 0 \pmod x$

thus $x=1,2,3,4,6,8,12,16,24,48$ and their sum is

$S = 124$.

Answer (score 2):

$51\equiv 3 \pmod x$ iff $x|51-3=48$. Divisors of $48$ are $1,2,3,4,6,8,12,16,24,48$ .

Comment: You are missing 12